# Comparison with mainstream workflow engines

Tags: spring-statemachine

I'd like to use Spring SM in my next future that has very simple workflows, 3-4 states, rule based transitions, and max actors.
The WF is pretty fixed, so storing its definition in java config is quite ok.
I'd prefer to use SM than WF engine which comes with the whole machinery, but I couldnt find out if there is a notion of Actor.
Meaning, only one particular user (determined by login string) can trigger a transition between states.

Also, can I run the same State machine definition in parallel. Is there a notion of instance, like process instance in WF jargon?

Thanks,
Milan

Answer (score 0):

Actor with a security is an interesting concept but we don't have anything build in right now. I'd say that this can be accomplished via Spring Security i.e. https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/ and there's more in its reference doc.

I could try to think if there's something what we could do to make this easier with Spring Security.

Parallel machines are on my todo list. It is a big topic so takes while to implement. Follow https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/35 and other related tickets. That issue is a foundation of making distributed state machines.